# How to eliminate drift with the magnetometer in the MPU9250

Tags: arduino-mega

I have a sketch running that uses a complementary filter for my X and Y values.

[image]

However, the Z value has no complementary filter (as you can tell by the slight drift when stationary) because I was told that a magnetometer is required to eliminate this drift. 
Thus I purchased the MPU9250.

How would a magnetometer be able to eliminate drift it only measures magnetic fields?

How would I be able to help reduce the drift?

Comment: I tried to answer this in your other question.

Comment: @chrisl yeah I saw thank you. Thought I should create a new post because the problems differ slightly so for anyone in the future needing help, the posts are sorted better